# Add product Api key to Strapi as product

Tags: strapi

I have made strapi API, but strapi give **auth** for the user role.
I'd like to give auth for valid API key like popular API.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is in our backlog here! https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/40-api-access-token-with-permissions

So my answer is customization to help you to have this feature. It will be no longer useful when we will release the feature.

We will use one method, but the important thing is the concept I will use.

First of all you will have to understand the customization concept https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html

Then to manage tokens you will have to create a `Token` content type with 2 attributes.

- token: that will be a string
- user: that will be a 1:1 relation with User.

When it's done, you will have to create a new entry (token and user) and link them together.

After that, we will update the way Strapi manage JWT to be able to manage an URL that will contain our `?token=my-token` token query params.

Here is the file that manages Strapi permission. We will have to customize it.
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js

So create a `./extensions/users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js` file and copy the original code in the file you just created.

After that you will have to customize the function.

With the following code, we allow managing the Authorization header and Token query parameter.

It will apply permissions of the related user of the token.

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  let role;

  if (
    (ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) ||
    (ctx.request.query && ctx.request.query.token)
    ) {
    try {

      let id;
      let isAdmin;

      if (ctx.request.query && ctx.request.query.token) {
        const [token] = await strapi.query('token').find({token: ctx.request.query.token})

        id = token.user.id;
        isAdmin = false;

        delete ctx.request.query.token;
      } else if (ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) {
        const decrypted = await strapi.plugins[
          'users-permissions'
        ].services.jwt.getToken(ctx);

        id = decrypted.id;
        isAdmin = decrypted.isAdmin || false;
      }

      if (id === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Invalid token: Token did not contain required fields');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on Jim's code a bit to better error handling:

````js
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  let role;

  if (
    (ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) ||
    (ctx.request.query && ctx.request.query.token)
  ) {
    try {

      let id;
      let isAdmin;

      if (ctx.request.query && ctx.request.query.token) {
        const [token] = await strapi.query('authtoken').find({token: ctx.request.query.token});

        if (!token) {
          return handleErrors(ctx, 'Your token is not valid', 'unauthorized');
        } else {
          if (token.user && typeof token.token === 'string') {
            id = token.user.id;
          }
          isAdmin = false;
        }

        delete ctx.request.query.token;
      } else if (ctx.request && ctx.request.header && ctx.request.header.authorization) {
        const decrypted = await strapi.plugins[
          'users-permissions'
        ].services.jwt.getToken(ctx);

        id = decrypted.id;
        isAdmin = decrypted.isAdmin || false;
      }

      if (id === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Invalid token: Token did not contain required fields');
      }
    ```
````